# How is the second printf("%d\n", n); being called?

Tags: c

```
// both() reads integers and prints the numbers in their original order
//   and then in reverse order.
// effects: reads input, produces output
void both(void) {
  int n = read_int();

  if(n != READ_INT_FAIL) {
  printf("%d\n", n);
  both();
  printf("%d\n", n);
  } 
}

 int main(void) {
   both();
 }
```

So this code reads ints and prints the number in their original order and in reverse. read_int() is a way my teachers implemented input. Anyways, say the input is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. The expected output is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 (obviously it would be newlines instead of commas but I didn't want to waste vertical space).

So my question is, How does this work?

From what I can trace in my head, `both()` gets called by main, and it keeps getting called before the second `printf()` can be accessed until the whole code is over because both won't be called when an invalid value (just any random letter after 5) is input.

How does this work?

Comment: Do you already know what _recursion_ is? Reading the Wikipedia article for it might help to understand this phenomenon.

Comment: BTW: you should [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your code properly.

Comment: what is the value of READ_INT_FAIL ?

Comment: READ_INT_FAIL is anything that isn't an integer. So it just stops the input basically. 
And also, I do know what recursion is.. but this example is hard to follow. The steps I see is:
1) main calls both()

2) n gets printed out for the first time

3) both() gets called again, so it prints out n again.

4) Then say there's a read_int_fail. Then the program stops.. And that's it

Comment: this program depends 'heavily' on the function: `read_int()`  However, you have not posted that function.  Please correct.  Note: is the function: `read_int()` the mess from the header file: `conio.h`?

Comment: if you think the program stops because the call to `read_int()` returned a failure condition, then you do not understand recursion

Answer (score 5):

When the recursion stops, the program doesn't end. The execution will continue after the inner `both` call. So This a quick following of program:

```
read_int = 1, print 1, call both() -> 1st recursion
read_int = 2, print 2, call both() -> 2nd recursion
read_int = 3, print 3, call both() -> 3rd recursion
read_int = 4, print 4, call both() -> 4th recursion
read_int = 5, print 5, call both() -> 5th recursion

read_int = 6, somehow the condition is true and the program continue at 5th recursion after the both() and print 5 again, so

5th recursion, print 5(second printf), end
4th recursion, print 4(second printf), end
3rd recursion, print 3(second printf), end
2nd recursion, print 2(second printf), end
1st recursion, print 1(second printf), end
```

Hope this helps the logic of the code and the execution.

Answer (score 1):

The thought in your head is absolutely correct in this case. As "both" function is being called in the same [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), execution of later lines will be on hold till the execution of newly called "both" function is finished. In computing theory this is called [recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/) and the condition which stops calling of the "both" (recursive) function is called [base case](https://www.quora.com/What-is-base-case-in-recursive-function-in-C-programming).

So the summary of calls look like:
i-input(value), p-printf(value), b-both(), rOi- rest of the code from both for input(value)

i(1)->p(1)->b()->i(2)->p(2)->b()->i(3)->p(3)->b()->i(4)->p(4)->b()->i(5)->p(5)->b()->i(invalid, if condition failed)->rOi(5)->rOi(4)->rOi(3)->rOi(2)->rOi(1)